# Use html5 canvas draw a circle but only show a part of it

Tags: html, html5-canvas, geometry

I have a canvas on my page

```
<canvas id="oneCanvas"  width="250px" heigth="250px"></canvas>​
```

then I want draw a circle on it

```
function drawCircle(theCanvas){
            var context=theCanvas.getContext('2d');
            context.beginPath();
            context.strokeStyle="#000000";
            context.lineWidth=50;
            context.arc(125,125,70,(Math.PI/180)*0,(Math.PI/180)*270,false);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();
        }
        $(function(){
            var theCanvas=document.getElementById('oneCanvas');
            drawCircle(theCanvas);
        });​
```

this code have a problem:

the circle only show a part,and the canvas's height seems short than 250px

here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JLNY3/2/)

So why this happened?How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, **`heigth`** is spelled incorrectly. The trailing `h` and the `t` have to be swapped: **`height`**.

```
<canvas id="oneCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>​
```

As for the "circle only show a part" problem: If you want to draw a full circle, draw from zero to 360 degrees. 270 degrees is just three-quarter of a circle.

```
    // *270 changed to *360
    context.arc(125, 125, 70, (Math.PI/180)*0, (Math.PI/180)*360, false);
    //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is zero, by the way
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/JLNY3/3/**